# Laravel CSRF expiry time

Tags: laravel

I don't want the CSRF token to expire before the session expires, so my question is if I increase the field `'lifetime' => 120` in `config/session.php` will it also increase the time that it takes for CSRF token to expire to match that value.

It is especially important because I want the sessions for my SPA to expire after 24 hours so `'lifetime' => 1440` but I don't want to CSRF tokens to expire after 2 hours.

Answer (score 3):

From 5.2 onwards `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::addCookieToResponse()` sets the cookie expiry from the lifetime setting on the session config.

```php
// from 5.5
$config = config('session');

$response->headers->setCookie(
    new Cookie(
        'XSRF-TOKEN', $request->session()->token(), $this->availableAt(60 * $config['lifetime']),
        $config['path'], $config['domain'], $config['secure'], false, false, $config['same_site'] ?? null
    )
);
```